# How to delete <span> tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to delete Parent and child tags of the `<span>`. How can I do this

```
<span id='dept1'>
Department
<span onClick='deleteDept();'>X</span>
</span>
<span id='dept2'>
Department2
<span onClick='deleteDept();'>X</span>
</span>
```

When I am Calling deleteDept() I want to delete total `<span>` (parent and child)

Any one help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the clicked element to the `deleteDept` method and then call the [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method on its parent element

```
<span id='dept1'>
    Department
    <span onClick='deleteDept(this);'>X</span>
</span>
<span id='dept2'>
    Department2
    <span onClick='deleteDept(this);'>X</span>
</span>
```

then in deleteDept()

```
function deleteDept(el) {
    //something else
    $(el).parent().remove();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ajsS3/)

But!!! since you are using jQuery the recommended solution will be use a jQuery event handler instead of an inline one

```
<span id='dept1'>
    Department
    <span class="dept-remove">X</span>
</span>
<span id='dept2'>
    Department2
    <span class="dept-remove">X</span>
</span>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.dept-remove').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b2uMW/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to only target specific elements, you only need to write more specific selectors.
For example, if you want to target only spans within a div, do

```
$("div span")
```

instead of

```
$("span");
```

jQuery 1.4 has a new `.unwrap()` method that would be very useful for this application.

Try this

```
$("div span font").contents().unwrap().unwrap();
```